# Blazor: Redirect user to another page on initilization, without rendering the original component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

UserCase:
Opening any route from the browser url, loads the component directly or initializes the component.
I want to decide where user should landup based on some api response.

I have tried to work with below but it does not work when if you paste the route directly in url bar.

App.Razor

```cs
public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            registration = navigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(async (context) => OnLocationChanging(navigationManager, context)); //does not get called in first load
            _initialized = true;
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    private static async ValueTask OnLocationChanging(NavigationManager navigationManager, LocationChangingContext context = null)
    {
        //call incase full page refresh

        var location = context?.TargetLocation ?? navigationManager.Uri;
        string path = location.Replace(navigationManager.BaseUri, "/");

        if (!RouteChecker.IsValidRoute(location, out path))
        {
            context?.PreventNavigation();
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(path);
        }

    }
```

Expectation:
Never load any component till the api is resolved.
If the API redirects redirect it to that page.

Comment: Fix the formatting of code, please.